# How to upload files to http directory in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, http

I have a windows forms application in VB.Net, and I am trying to upload a photo to a local http address `http://10.0.0.13/MyStorageDevice/`.

When opening this address from my browser it requests a username and a password. I can then log in with the correct username and password, and it shows list of all files uploaded to this path.

I tried to use `WebClient.UploadFile` but its not working. I read all the details in the msdn documentation here:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx

Whats the wrong here ?

```
Dim uriString As String = "http://10.0.0.13/MyStorageDevice/"

' Create a new WebClient instance.
Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()            
myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
myWebClient.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password")

' Upload the file to the URI.
' The 'UploadFile(uriString,fileName)' method implicitly uses HTTP POST method. 
Dim responseArray As Byte() = myWebClient.UploadFile(uriString, "C:\Users\areej\Pictures\pic1.png")
```

The code throws this exception:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405)
>   Method Not Allowed.    at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address,
>   String method, String fileName)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(String address, String fileName)

How can I fix this?

Comment: and what do you have on your server you cant just upload a file to any random adress

Comment: Without any code, how would you manually upload a file?

Comment: @Mederic I want to upload the file to the base address concatenated with the file name for example http://10.0.0.13/SEDCOStorageDevice/pic1.png

Comment: @the_lotus I can open it from the network and sharing center in my PC and copy the file to.

Comment: I think you need maybe to read about internet and directories. You c'ant upload a file to a directory just by saying upload. either you need to use FTP to send the file to a webserver or use for instance POST like in your code but that means you need a file to receive the data in PHP for example. If its a network on your network or linked then you can connect to it and just File.Copy

Comment: @AreejQadomi then that's how you would do it. connect to the network and copy the files. That would normaly be a simple IO operation.

Comment: @the_lotus there are two cases, if the network path exists I have to connect to network, but if the network path is not available I have to connect to that http path and I don't know what to do

Comment: @Mederic how to pass username and password if I used File.Copy??

Comment: @AreejQadomi please take the time to go and read the basics about how the Web works, how directories work and also how network connections work in windows. I think you didn't take the time to learn the basics before trying to code as you are mixing a lot of things up

Comment: @Mederic I am sorry but can you supply me with useful articles I can read? I have been searching and reading all the time but in the wrong places and wrong keywords. I don't want to waste more time :(

Comment: I would first test whether the authentication is working. Are you able to download the html for the directory listing? Get that working first, and then attempt the upload.